# SQL query: search value in array inside cell

Tags: mysql

I have tried a lot of syntax but nothing is working.
I have MySQL 8.0.31 with phpMyAdmin 5.1.1.

My table looks like this (the column I want to filter by):

[image: photo]

The thing is, I'm saving in this field some order numbers, and I need to make a SELECT statement in which I have one order number (for example, 1632) and I need to determine if this number is stored inside the "array" of orders in any of the rows (in this example, the desired result of the query is the third row).

I have tried the IN statement without result.
If I use the LIKE statement obviously works, but in case of larger numbers (like 16320), if I'm searching for 1632, I will find also this value.

The separator of the numbers, if works with another one, is able to be changed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would do it as such

```
SELECT * FROM Orders
WHERE Ordernes LIKE '%,$searchValue,%' OR Ordernes 
LIKE '$searchValue,%' OR Ordernes LIKE '%,$searchValue';
```

If you add the seperators on both sides you will only find the value that you are looking for and not numbers that look like it.

Comment: I'm not pretty sure if this solution can help me, because as you can see in the picture, the value between others has a comma on both sides, but the first and last value of the chain doesn't have it, so they will never be founded.

Comment: Ah yes totally forgot about that. Let me look into it a bit further

Comment: I also though on that solution, including at the beginning and the ending a comma, then with my php explode the chain by the comma and with FOR statement exclude the first and last results (the ones empty), but I would enjoy to learn a proper way to make this properly.

Comment: You want it just as an SQL query right? Or with PHP too

Comment: Honestly I found a way that kind of works but I don't really know if its considered clean, I'll update the answer

Comment: the SQL query is made from PHP, so meanwhile the execution returns the desired result, I don't care the type of syntax used.

Comment: Hope this works for you

Comment: I guess this solution is not good because imagine I'm looking for 1632 and I have 21632 and 16320 in the database, if I use '%$searchValue,%' I will find 21632 too, and using '%,$searchValue%' I will find 16320 too

Comment: You didn't look at it correctly, the two OR's select for the first and last in the array, so they don't have % infront or behind.

Comment: `LIKE '$searchValue,%' OR Ordernes LIKE '%,$searchValue';`

Comment: The two or statements search for the value without the , infront of behind so if the number is in the beginning or at the end of the query it will find it, however it won't search for numbers like 16320 if you only search 1632

Comment: oh yeahh my fault this time, I will try the result, maybe can fit me